# Auto layout: changing a view's center x alignment programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have an image view that is x centered to another label above it.

After tapping a button, I want that image view to be x centered to another label. I tried connecting the constraint to an outlet and replacing it with a new NSLayoutConstraint (since I cannot modify the Second Item) then calling layoutIfNeeded on the parent view, but it doesn't seem to change.

```
[self.tabsView layoutIfNeeded];
self.tabIndicatorCenterXAlignment = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:self.tabIndicatorIV
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:_tabsBtnArray[pageNumber]
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:
 ^{
     [self.tabsView layoutIfNeeded];
 }];
```

Comment: You do need to remove the old one before adding the new one. In your  posted code, you never add tabIndicatorCenterXAlignment to a view.

Comment: Oh right, tried that and it's working now. Thought that you can just update the constraint if its connected to an outlet like Width or Height constraint. Thanks!

Comment: No, if self.tabIndicatorCenterXAlignment is an outlet, the code you have just makes your pointer point to a new thing -- it neither removes the old constraint nor adds the new one.

Comment: @JustinLeo Got any Working Solution?